# ¿Cómo puedo anular los estilos predefinidos de @angular/material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, style

Estaba siguiendo un tutorial en el cual se ejecutaba el siguiente comando:

```
ng add @angular/material

? Choose a prebuilt theme name, or "custom" for a custom theme: Indigo/Pink        [ Preview: https://material.angular.io?theme=indigo-pink ]
? Set up global Angular Material typography styles? Yes
? Set up browser animations for Angular Material? Yes
```

Es obvio que me iba a cambiar el estilo de todo el proyecto, pero siguiendo el tutorial ni me he dado cuenta y me he destrozado todo el estilo del proyecto, estaba utilizando los estilos de Boostrap, al aplicar Indigo/Pink ya nada me cuadra.

¿Alguien sabe como puedo anular el comando para volver a cómo estaba?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Entiendo perfectamente tu predicamento. Ahora, mi consejo (que no es la solución) es que cuando trabajes con Angular, evites la versión de Bootstrap que usa JQuery como dependencia. Existe `ng-bootstrap` para trabajar Bootstrap con Angular y por supuesto existe Angular Material, que se basa en los estilos de Material Design. Saludos

Comment: Hola Mauricio gracias por contestar, tendré en cuenta tu consejo para futuros casos. Sabes si puedo eliminar las dependencias de Angular Material con algun comando¿? He estado investigando pero no encuentro nada...

Comment: Para eliminar el paquete añadido deberías usar `npm uninstall <nombre del paquete>`, eso sólo elimina la dependencia, luego debes revertir manualmente los cambios realizados por el CLI de Angular y eso es ya algo más laborioso, ya que no solo debes editar el `package.json` sino tal vez eliminar la referencia a la hoja de estilos. No veo otra solución. Lamentablemente no existe el comando `ng remove`. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue fácil, entras en el archivo angular.json, una vez dentro buscas con CTRL + F el nombre de las dependencias que quieras eliminar, en mi caso: Indigo/Pink, y borras allá donde aparezca.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]